# Change URL and redirect using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, redirect

I have some code like this,

```
<form id="abc">
  <input type="text" id="txt" />
</form>
```

and now I want to redirect like this,

```
var temp = $("#txt").val();
url = "http://example.com/" + temp;
window.location.replace(url);
// or window.location(url);
```

Is there anyway in jQuery to solve this? It still lets me have `url = http://example.com`.

Comment: Thank alot all of you! Now I still do not know what difference between window.location and window.location.replace. In my example I've just need to post url to my page like that: http://abc.com/abc to get abc to search in my database with abc is what user typing in put and press enter or button but they always return http://abc.com?name=abc so I think I can trigger in submit event to redirect and change my url to what I want but they still do nothing. That's all, by the way thank you again!

Comment: I explained the difference between window.location and window.location.replace here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846954/change-url-and-redirect-in-jquery/847130#847130

Answer (score 350):

As mentioned in the other answers, you don't need jQuery to do this; you can just use the standard properties.

However, it seems you don't seem to know the difference between `window.location.replace(url)` and `window.location = url`.

1. `window.location.replace(url)` replaces the current location in the address bar by a new one. The page that was calling the function, won't be included in the browser history. Therefore, on the new location, clicking the back button in your browser would make you go back to the page you were viewing before you visited the document containing the redirecting JavaScript.
2. `window.location = url` redirects to the new location. On this new page, the back button in your browser would point to the original page containing the redirecting JavaScript.

Of course, both have their use cases, but it seems to me like in this case you should stick with the latter.

P.S.: You probably forgot two slashes after `http:` on line 2 of your JavaScript:

```
url = "http://abc.example/" + temp;
```

Comment: But to be very correct you should set window.location.href instead of window.location. While both work nowadays the latter is an object (and of course unsupported to assign a string to in an ancient IE version...)

Comment: @Victor That doesn’t list any ancient IE version where this breaks in. @bobince’s comment is correct: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10016109/96656#comment18225061_10016109

Comment: Minus 1. Not enough jQuery

Answer (score 50):

tell you the true, I still don't get what you need, but

```
window.location(url);
```

should be

```
window.location = url;
```

a search on [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) reference will tell you that.

Answer (score 17):

jQuery does not have an option for this, nor should it have one. This is perfectly valid javascript and there is no reason for jQuery to provide wrapper functions for this.

jQuery is just a library on top of javascript, even if you use jQuery you can still use normal javascript.

Btw window.location is not a function but a property which you should set like this:

```
window.location = url;
```

Comment: down vote for claiming jQuery does not have a method for this (even though it is unnecessary overkill and should not be recommended)
    
    $jq(window).attr("location","http://yourdomain.com");
or

    $(location).attr('href',url);

Comment: Upvoted to undo that downvote. Pim's response can easily read as "there is no specific method in jQuery for this." To downvote on lexical semantics is a misuse of that privilege.

Comment: Upvoted because you know... it is right "there is no specific method in jQuery for this.", why would you like to have a such ugly solution as:
 $jq(window).attr("location","yourdomain.com"); 
when you can have something like
window.location = url;

Answer (score 14):

```
var temp="/yourapp/";
$(location).attr('href','http://abcd.example'+temp);
```

Try this...
used as an alternative

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
$("#abc").attr("action", "/yourapp/" + temp).submit();
```

What it means:

Find a form with `id` "abc", change it's `attribute` named "action" and then submit it...

This works for me... !!!

Comment: lol, that is some funny S! I like the idea though. Points for being creative!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this with jQuery (why?) you should get the DOM window.location object to use its functions:

```
$(window.location)[0].replace("https://www.google.it");
```

Note that [0] says to jQuery to use directly the DOM object and not the $(window.location) jQuery object incapsulating the DOM object.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like:

```
var url = "http://example.com/" + temp;
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do it simpler without jquery

```
location = "https://example.com/" + txt.value
```

```js
function send() {
  location = "https://example.com/" + txt.value;
}
```

```html
<form id="abc">
  <input type="text" id="txt" />
</form>

<button onclick="send()">Send</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, and I can't see how it could. location is not a global. window.location is.

edit: Yep verified. It doesnt work, at least not in chrome. Consider updating your example to window.location

Comment: Strange - in my chrome, firefox, safari it works - the location is global property - e.g. when I type in chrome console: `location = 'https://google.com'` then it change page - do you try on other browsers?

Comment: @Shayne when you type `this` and `this.location` in console - what do you see?

Comment: this.location only works when "this" is referring to the window. Which is rarely going to be the case. Explicit is always better than Implicit, especially if you don't want to be surprised when your code isn't portable or reusable

Comment: Yes you're right - however I wonder: why in your browser `this` not refer to `window` object (and above snippet dont works) ? (in browsers global context it should be set to windows [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call))