# How can I disable HREF if onclick is executed?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, anchor, href

I have an anchor with *both* `HREF` and `ONCLICK` attributes set. If clicked and Javascript is enabled, I want it to *only* execute `ONCLICK` and ignore `HREF`. Likewise, if Javascript is disabled or unsupported, I want it to follow the `HREF` URL and ignore `ONCLICK`. Below is an example of what I'm doing, which would execute the JS and follow the link concurrently (usually the JS is executed and then the page changes):

```
<A HREF="http://example.com/no-js-login" ONCLICK="yes_js_login()">Log in</A>
```

**what's the best way to do this?**

I'm hoping for a Javascript answer, but I'll accept any method as long as it works, especially if this can be done with PHP.
I've read "[a href link executes and redirects page before javascript onclick function is able to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712528/a-href-link-executes-and-redirects-page-before-javascript-onclick-function-is-ab)" already, but it only delays `HREF`, but doesn't completely disable it. I'm also looking for something much simpler.

Comment: I would use to anchors one with an href and one without. On page load check if javascript is enabled, if it is show the correct anchor else show the other.

Comment: @ewein Why? That sounds like an awful lot of markup for a simple feature.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use the first un-edited solution, if you put return first in the `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href="https://example.com/no-js-login" onclick="return yes_js_login();">Log in</a>

yes_js_login = function() {
     // Your code here
     return false;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/FXkgV/289/

Comment: Over the past couple years I've changed my mind; this is a better solution

Comment: How wholesome !

Comment: But this is not working with JSX react. Will this work?

Comment: this saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 63):

```
    yes_js_login = function() {
         // Your code here
         return false;
    }
```

If you return false it should prevent the default action (going to the href).

**Edit:** Sorry that doesn't seem to work, you can do the following instead:

```
<a href="http://example.com/no-js-login" onclick="yes_js_login(); return false;">Link</a>
```

Comment: The edited answer does not answer the question, as it removes the actual link.

Comment: alternatively use `onclick="return yes_js_login();"` with `yes_js_login` returning `false`

Comment: @cgogolin see my answer.

Comment: for anyone who still stuck, may adding this line `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Answer (score 51):

Simply disable default browser behaviour using [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and pass the `event` within your HTML.

`<a href=/foo onclick= yes_js_login(event)>Lorem ipsum</a>`

```
yes_js_login = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: return false did not work in polymer... above solution did work... Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You can use this simple code:

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;">add new action</a><br>
```

Answer (score 19):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="ignore-click">Test</a>
```

**with jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(".ignore-click").click(function(){
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

**with JavaScript**

```
<script>
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("ignore-click").length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("ignore-click")[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        }
</script>
```

You assign class `.ignore-click` to as many elements you like and clicks on those elements will be ignored

Comment: This is a great solution! I used it for buttons that I have that when clicked a pseudo class `.btn-loading` is added to the clicked link, then if successful a checkmark(on error an X) replaces the loading animation. I don't want the button to be able to be clicked again in some instances(for both success and error), using this I can simply `$(elemnent).addClass('disabled')` and easily achieve the functionality I was looking in an elegant way!

Comment: I don't know why my code does not work?

var modal_button = document.querySelectorAll('[href="#bookingform"]');
  if(modal_button.length){    
    for (var i = 0; i < modal_button.length; i++) {
      modal_button[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        // some code
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      });
    }
  }

Answer (score 7):

It's simpler if you pass an event parameter like this:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="yes_js_login(event);">link</a>
```

```javascript
function yes_js_login(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I have to use e.preventDefault()

Comment: onclick="event.stopImmediatePropagation();" works for me

Answer (score 7):

Try using `javascript:void(0)` as follows-

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="...">Text</a>`

Comment: Thank you for chipping in. This doesn't help the scenario that I posed in my original question: "If clicked and Javascript is enabled, I want it to only execute `ONCLICK` and ignore `HREF`. Likewise, if Javascript is disabled or unsupported, I want it to follow the `HREF` URL and ignore `ONCLICK`."

Answer (score 2):

This might help.
**No JQuery needed**

```
<a href="../some-relative-link/file" 
onclick="this.href = 'https://docs.google.com/viewer?url='+this.href; this.onclick = '';" 
target="_blank">
```

This code does the following:
Pass the relative link to [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)

1. Get the full link version of the anchor by `this.href`
2. open the link the the new window.

So in your case this might work:

```
<a href="../some-relative-link/file" 
onclick="this.href = 'javascript:'+console.log('something has stopped the link'); " 
target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a situation where I needed a template for the  element that would handle alternatively a regular URL or a javascript call, where the js function needs a reference to the calling  element. In javascript, "this" works as a self reference only in the context of a form element, e.g., a button. I didn't want a button, just the apperance of a regular link.

Examples:

```
<a onclick="http://blahblah" href="http://blahblah" target="_blank">A regular link</a>
<a onclick="javascript:myFunc($(this));return false" href="javascript:myFunc($(this));"  target="_blank">javascript with self reference</a>
```

The href and onClick attributes have the same values, exept I append "return false" on onClick when it's a javascript call. Having "return false" in the called function did not work.

Comment: why are there two? Why are you putting JS in the `HREF`?

Comment: Supuhstar, The actual code is dynamic, javascript, and will generate an <a> element for several hundred items that are defined externally. Each item will either specify a static link address, and thats where the generated <a> element should use the regular "href behaviour". Or, a javascript function call is specified for the item, in which case the <a> element's behaviour is calculated, based on the element's context.
And in the code for the <a> generator, I just wanted to copy whatever is specified for each element, no testing whether it's a link address or a javascript funtion call.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question. Who said I wanted several hundred links? I really don't understand the point of all this, or even half of what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a condition when the user click the "a" element.  The condition was:

If other section had more than ten items, then the user should be not redirected to other page.

If other section had less than ten items, then the user should be redirected to other page.

The functionality of the "a" elements depends of the other component. The code within click event is the follow:

```
var elementsOtherSection = document.querySelectorAll("#vehicle-item").length;
if (elementsOtherSection> 10){
     return true;
}else{
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;
}
```