# Disable onClick event if anchor href link was executed

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a table.
Each row is a link to some page(for example - google.com) which called by js "***onClick window.open***" method:

```
<tr  class='tr' onClick="win=window.open('http://google.com');win.focus();" >
```

In the last column I have an ***anchor href*** link to other page (for example - `jsfiddle`):

```
<td class='td'><a href = "http://jsfiddle.net">JSFiddle</a></td>
```

If I click on anchor link it's opened, but also opened the first page called by onClick.

I've found a reverse issue:

[How can I disable HREF if onclick is executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622100/how-to-disable-href-if-onclick-is-executed)

We can disable href by adding "return false" to onClick Event.

Is it possible to prevent onClick executing if anchor link was clicked?

Here is my demo: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyjDZ/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to change approach a little. Inline event handlers are never good idea. Consider this code.

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr data-url="http://google.com">
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td><a href="http://jsfiddle.net">JSFiddle</a></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

JS:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');

table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var target = e.target;
    if (target.tagName == 'A') {
        return false;
    }

    if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
        var win = window.open(target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-url'));
        win.focus();
    }
}, false);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CqRE9/

Comment: Thank you, I see it works in demo but somehow not works on my real site, I will investigate it.

Comment: I found my problem - it works if we add js script after table output and not works contrariwise... I always used to add all js scripts in the start of page(in the head tags). Why it doesn't work in my way?

Comment: Because if you add script before table, it will execute before DOM is loaded. Hence by the time of execution there is no table in the document.

Comment: Could you please help, how it should be changed if I attach script from external src? I suppose it something like `window.onload=table.addEventListener ...` but I can't find correct way

Comment: Just include script tag before closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Yes, it works... but it's not very good way to add a new js file in a lot of files... Maybe possible to have a src script in a head of document and specify "onload" method for it?

Comment: Why can't use add src script before closing body?

Comment: I just don't like to have multiple "includes" in a different places, it's hard to maintain afterwards. Anyway, thank you, if I find another way, I'll post here.

Comment: Then you should use `DOMContentLoaded` or `window.onload` events.

Comment: Yes, if I place your code in function `window.onload = function(){ your script };` all works fine even if script included in the head of the page. That's what I needed! Please update your answer or I can, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible!

```
$("tr").on("click", function(){ 
 $(this).attr("onClick", false); 
});
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyjDZ/3/)

Comment: Now it doesn't work in demo... do we need to include jquery for this?

Comment: Sorry, I see jquery is attached, but it doesn't work - you can see that both links are opened when you click on anchor link...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it showed up first in my search results and I suspect the suggested answer is a little more complicated than it needs to be. I found that if I add `onclick="event.stopPropagation()"` to my anchor, only the anchor is invoked, and the parent element's click handler is not. Works perfectly for my use case.