# change URL without reloading the page with <a href=" ">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For modify the URL without reloading the page we can use:

```
window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');
```

but if I try it with `<a>` element :

```
<a onClick='my_function()' href='/page2.php'> Click Here </a>
<script>
function my_fnuction(){
    window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');

}
 </script>
```

It will not work, So how can I use `<a>`  element and `window.history.pushState()` together? 
Like twitter and Facebook, user can click on the right button to open the URL in new window, and direct click to get pages and change the URL without reloading

Comment: `onClick='my_function()'` and `function my_fnuction()` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In onclick you have `my_function` where as the actual function name is `my_fnuction`.
2. You need to cancel the default behaviour, If your onclick function returns false the default browser behaviour is cancelled.

**Code:**

```
<a onClick='return my_function()' href='/page2.php'> Click Here </a>
<script>
function my_function(){
    window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');
    return false;
}
 </script>
```

Comment: @Mi-Creativity missed it. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: it wasn't your mistake, it's in the post, I apologize

Answer (score 1):

add `return false;` make it so that `href` is not executed, also add `return` to your `onclick` value:

```
<a onClick='return my_function()' href='/page2.php'> Click Here </a>
<script>
function my_function(){
    window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');
    return false;
}
</script>
```

solution is also is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622100/how-can-i-disable-href-if-onclick-is-executed)

Answer (score 1):

Probably just preventing the default behavior of anchor tag. Returning false to the event

```
<a onClick='return my_function()' href='/page2.php'> Click Here </a>
<script>
function my_function(){
    window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');
return false;

}
 </script>
```

Or using prevent default:

```
<a onClick='my_function(event); ' href='/page2.php'> Click Here </a>
<script>
function my_function(e){
    window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');
e.preventDefault();
}
 </script>
```