# How to overwrite anchor element's href target and remove other bugs in my click-to-go-to-target javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a webpage. I want to implimenet the feature which scrolls the webpage to the location of href target of menu anchors. My code is as following

```js
 var myscroll = {};
 myscroll.list = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");

 myscroll.bodypos = function getScrollY() {
   scrOfY = 0;
   if (typeof(window.pageYOffset) == 'number') {
     //Netscape compliant
     scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;

   } else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop)) {
     //DOM compliant
     scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;

   } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop)) {
     //IE6 standards compliant mode
     scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

   }
   return scrOfY;
 }

 function getScrollpos(idname) {
   return document.getElementById(idname).offsetTop;
 }
 myscroll.point = [];
 myscroll.point[0] = getScrollpos("home");
 myscroll.point[1] = getScrollpos("artists");
 myscroll.point[2] = getScrollpos("songs");
 myscroll.point[3] = getScrollpos("beats");
 myscroll.point[4] = getScrollpos("contact");

 function removeclass() {
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     myscroll.list[i].className = "";
   }
 }

 window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[0]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[0].className = "active";
   }


   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[1]) {
     removeclass();

     myscroll.list[1].className = "active";
   }

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[2]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[2].className = "active";

   }

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[3]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[3].className = "active";

   }

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[4]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[4].className = "active";

   }
 });

 for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

   (function(j) {

     myscroll.list[j].anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
     myscroll.list[j].anchor.addEventListener("click", function() {



       if ((document.body.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.body.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j])) {

         var clr1 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.body.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j] - 10) {
             document.body.scrollTop += 3;
           } else {
             document.body.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr1);
           }
         }, 1);
       }



       if ((document.documentElement.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.documentElement.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j])) {

         var clr2 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j] - 10) {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop += 3;
           } else {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr2);
           }
         }, 1);
       }


       if ((document.body.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.body.scrollTop > myscroll.point[j])) {
         var clr3 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.body.scrollTop >= myscroll.point[j] + 4) {
             document.body.scrollTop -= 3;
           } else {
             document.body.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr3);
           }

         }, 1);
       }

       if ((document.documentElement.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.documentElement.scrollTop > myscroll.point[j])) {
         var clr4 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= myscroll.point[j] + 4) {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop -= 3;
           } else {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr4);
           }

         }, 1);
       }
       alert(j);

     }, true);

   }(j));

 }
```

```css
#navbar,
#navbar a:link,
#navbar a:visited,
#navbar a:hover {
  position: fixed;
  color: red !important;
}
#home {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}
#artists {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: block;
}
#songs {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
#beats {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
#contact {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#artists">Artists</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#songs">Songs</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#beats">Beats</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="home"></div>
<div id="artists"></div>
<div id="songs"></div>
<div id="beats"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

As such the code doesn't do what it is supposed to. If we remove `href` attributes of menu's anchor tags then the code works as expected but with one bug. The problem with the `href` tags is that before the `onclick` function could do anything the webpages scrolls quickly to the `href target`. [Other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622100/how-can-i-disable-href-if-onclick-is-executed) say returntning false with onclick would disable the `href` target. The problem is that I am not using `onclick`; I am using `addEventListener("click")`. I tried returning both `false` and `true` but nothing worked. So,

- Why is it said returning `false` stops href function of anchor elements? Now I know that `preventDefault` will do what I want. But I want to know how to acheive the same by returning false.

Now comes the bug. When I click on `contact` link it scrolls down to the bottom of page and remains fixed there. If I scroll upwards then the page is automatically scrolled to bottom.

```js
 var myscroll = {};
 myscroll.list = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");

 myscroll.bodypos = function getScrollY() {
   scrOfY = 0;
   if (typeof(window.pageYOffset) == 'number') {
     //Netscape compliant
     scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;

   } else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop)) {
     //DOM compliant
     scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;

   } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop)) {
     //IE6 standards compliant mode
     scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

   }
   return scrOfY;
 }

 function getScrollpos(idname) {
   return document.getElementById(idname).offsetTop;
 }
 myscroll.point = [];
 myscroll.point[0] = getScrollpos("home");
 myscroll.point[1] = getScrollpos("artists");
 myscroll.point[2] = getScrollpos("songs");
 myscroll.point[3] = getScrollpos("beats");
 myscroll.point[4] = getScrollpos("contact");

 function removeclass() {
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     myscroll.list[i].className = "";
   }
 }

 window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[0]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[0].className = "active";
   }


   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[1]) {
     removeclass();

     myscroll.list[1].className = "active";
   }

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[2]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[2].className = "active";

   }

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[3]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[3].className = "active";

   }

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[4]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[4].className = "active";

   }
 });

 for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

   (function(j) {

     myscroll.list[j].anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
     myscroll.list[j].anchor.addEventListener("click", function(event) {


          event.preventDefault();
       if ((document.body.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.body.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j])) {

         var clr1 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.body.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j] - 10) {
             document.body.scrollTop += 3;
           } else {
             document.body.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr1);
           }
         }, 1);
       }



       if ((document.documentElement.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.documentElement.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j])) {

         var clr2 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j] - 10) {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop += 3;
           } else {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr2);
           }
         }, 1);
       }


       if ((document.body.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.body.scrollTop > myscroll.point[j])) {
         var clr3 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.body.scrollTop >= myscroll.point[j] + 4) {
             document.body.scrollTop -= 3;
           } else {
             document.body.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr3);
           }

         }, 1);
       }

       if ((document.documentElement.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.documentElement.scrollTop > myscroll.point[j])) {
         var clr4 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= myscroll.point[j] + 4) {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop -= 3;
           } else {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr4);
           }

         }, 1);
       }
       alert(j);

     }, true);

   }(j));

 }
```

```css
#navbar,
#navbar a:link,
#navbar a:visited,
#navbar a:hover {
  position: fixed;
  color: red !important;
}
#home {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}
#artists {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: block;
}
#songs {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
#beats {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
#contact {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#artists">Artists</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#songs">Songs</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#beats">Beats</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="home"></div>
<div id="artists"></div>
<div id="songs"></div>
<div id="beats"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

- How do I remove this bug?

Comment: I wonder if this is what you are looking for : https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: @Andrew Can we do this `preventDefault` function in plain javascript too?

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault()` on the event, to stop the default for the `click` event to be executed.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Then do your thing in your handler, and at the end, manually update the `window.location` with the value of the event target's `href` attribute.

**EDIT**

RE the comment: your event still bubbles, only the default action is prevented. To stop it from bubbling up, there is `event.stopPropagation()`.

The default action for you event is simply to set the `window.location` to the value of your event target's `href` attribute

```
window.location = e.target.getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: Isn't there anything like `allowDefault()` which I could execute after my javascript function is finished? OR isn't there any way I could _reorder_ the execution of default behaviour and my javascript function. Something like bubbling?

Comment: I added it to my answer

Comment: There is a problem `window.location = e.target.getAttribute('href');` adds the `href` target before jquery function is executed. It causes a blinking effect.

Comment: You have to add it at the end of what you are doing. So, probably in the callback function of whatever jQuery thing you do. So it actually only updates `windows.location` once everything else is done.

Comment: Since I couldn't remove the bug of my custom javascript which I mentioned in the question. I replaced the code on live site with the following jquery code: `$(myscroll.list[j].anchor).click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: myscroll.point[j]
   }, 2000);
   
   window.location = event.target.getAttribute('href');
   
  });` But now the problem is that window.location is updated before scrolling animation of jquery finishes.