# Why is 58 being added to array elements in my code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging

I've made a website here http://sycoscientistrecords.github.io . I have used the following code to determine the positions of various divs:

```
myscroll = {};
function getScrollpos(idname) {
    return document.getElementById(idname).offsetTop;
}
myscroll.point = [];
myscroll.idnames = []; 
myscroll.point[0] = getScrollpos("home");
myscroll.point[1] = getScrollpos("artists");
myscroll.point[2] = getScrollpos("songs");
myscroll.point[3] = getScrollpos("beats");
myscroll.point[4] = getScrollpos("contact");
```

The problem is that `getScrollpos("beats");` returns `2766` but `myscroll.point[3]` returns `3124`. Similarly `getScrollpos("contact")` return `3668` but `myscroll.point[4]` return `4046`. On the other hand `myscroll.point[0]` and `getScrollpos("home")` both return the same value. And `myscroll.point[1] and getScrollpos("artists")` return same values too. Even if I remove all other javascript code from the source file the issue remains.

**Question:** Why is 58 being added to third and fourth array elements in my code?

P.S: Although you can directly open the code of my website in dev tools. I've made a basic architecture with same javascript code to imitate the problem with the following code:

```js
 var myscroll = {};
 myscroll.list = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");

 myscroll.bodypos = function getScrollY() {
   scrOfY = 0;
   if (typeof(window.pageYOffset) == 'number') {
     //Netscape compliant
     scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;

   } else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop)) {
     //DOM compliant
     scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;

   } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop)) {
     //IE6 standards compliant mode
     scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

   }
   return scrOfY;
 }

 function getScrollpos(idname) {
   return document.getElementById(idname).offsetTop;
 }
 myscroll.point = [];
 myscroll.point[0] = getScrollpos("home");
 myscroll.point[1] = getScrollpos("artists");
 myscroll.point[2] = getScrollpos("songs");
 myscroll.point[3] = getScrollpos("beats");
 myscroll.point[4] = getScrollpos("contact");

 function removeclass() {
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     myscroll.list[i].className = "";
   }
 }

 window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[0]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[0].className = "active";
   }


   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[1]) {
     removeclass();

     myscroll.list[1].className = "active";
   }

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[2]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[2].className = "active";

   }

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[3]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[3].className = "active";

   }

   if (myscroll.bodypos() >= myscroll.point[4]) {
     removeclass();
     myscroll.list[4].className = "active";

   }
 });

 for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

   (function(j) {

     myscroll.list[j].anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-right")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[j].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
     myscroll.list[j].anchor.addEventListener("click", function(event) {


          event.preventDefault();
       if ((document.body.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.body.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j])) {

         var clr1 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.body.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j] - 10) {
             document.body.scrollTop += 3;
           } else {
             document.body.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr1);
           }
         }, 1);
       }



       if ((document.documentElement.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.documentElement.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j])) {

         var clr2 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < myscroll.point[j] - 10) {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop += 3;
           } else {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr2);
           }
         }, 1);
       }


       if ((document.body.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.body.scrollTop > myscroll.point[j])) {
         var clr3 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.body.scrollTop >= myscroll.point[j] + 4) {
             document.body.scrollTop -= 3;
           } else {
             document.body.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr3);
           }

         }, 1);
       }

       if ((document.documentElement.scrollTop != undefined) && (document.documentElement.scrollTop > myscroll.point[j])) {
         var clr4 = setInterval(function() {
           if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= myscroll.point[j] + 4) {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop -= 3;
           } else {
             document.documentElement.scrollTop = myscroll.point[j];
             clearInterval(clr4);
           }

         }, 1);
       }
       alert(j);

     }, true);

   }(j));

 }
```

```css
#navbar,
#navbar a:link,
#navbar a:visited,
#navbar a:hover {
  position: fixed;
  color: red !important;
}
#home {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}
#artists {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: block;
}
#songs {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
#beats {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
#contact {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#artists">Artists</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#songs">Songs</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#beats">Beats</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="home"></div>
<div id="artists"></div>
<div id="songs"></div>
<div id="beats"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post your html also please?

Comment: @Verthosa Do you want me to post the whole html code of my website?

Comment: I can a post a wireframe version of my code like I did in my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37298414/3429430

Comment: @user31782, Just a fiddle or executable demo to understand what is going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I did some research in Google Chrome. After visiting your site I opened developer console (F12) and executed your code. Here are results:

```
myscroll = {};
function getScrollpos(idname) {
    return document.getElementById(idname).offsetTop;
}
myscroll.point = [];
myscroll.idnames = []; 
myscroll.point[0] = getScrollpos("home");
myscroll.point[1] = getScrollpos("artists");
myscroll.point[2] = getScrollpos("songs");
myscroll.point[3] = getScrollpos("beats");
myscroll.point[4] = getScrollpos("contact");

getScrollpos("home");
// 0
getScrollpos("songs");
// 1202
getScrollpos("beats");
// 2017
getScrollpos("contact");
// 2857
myscroll.point
// [0, 420, 1202, 2017, 2857]
```

Looks like everything is OK.

Comment: I think the problem appears on small screen desktops only. Try small screen size in mobile view of chrome dev tools.

Comment: You have probably resized window after saving values to array, therefore `getScrollpos()` returns actual value which is not equal to saved one.

Comment: No I just checked the website on small screen size computer.

Answer (score 0):

Due to how it "measures", the result of

```
getScrollpos("beats");
```

Might change depending on you displaying the developer console or not when you call the function, is it possible that the difference comes from the way you are testing?

Try it out, depending on how tall you make the dev console, that function will return different values.

Comment: But then why does only result of `getScrollpos("beats");` and `getScrollpos("contact");` is changed. Why isn't other values like `getScrollpos("songs"); changed.