# Don't open href while an onClick is specified (in react js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Our `<a>` tag opens a custom pdf viewer in our application by providing a function to the `onClick` property.

We want to provide a href for accessibility, so users can rightclick -> open in new tab, control+click or what else they fancy.

However, when the user clicks the `<a>` tag, we don't want to actually open the link, instead our `onClick` function should handle the event.

currently we have somthing like this:

```
render(){
  return (<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" onClick={(e)=>this.linkClick(e)} >click here</a>)
}

linkClick(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); // does not stop the link from opening
   console.log("link clicked");
   return false; // does not stop the link from opening
}
```

In plain js this can be done by [returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622100/how-can-i-disable-href-if-onclick-is-executed) on the onClick function.
We've also tried adding `stopPropagation()` to no avail.
Some react users add `href="javascript: void(0)"` while this does disable the link, it does not meet our accessibility needs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `preventDefault`. Returning `false` [has been deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/28/react-v0.12.html#deprecations) since React 0.12.

```
linkClick(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log("link clicked");
}
```

Comment: Welp, Another day to be surprised by my own stupidity. I guess preventDefault slipped my mind, due to an overfocus on stopPropagation.
Thanks!