# Implement onclick on anchor element while omitting href

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen implementing `onclick` on `a` element in different ways, but i don't know **How each one different from another in event?**

What i want when i click on `a` i would like to have `onclick event` happen without `href` **do nothing**.

`<a href="#" onclick="myFunc()">Submit</a>`
`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunc()">Submit</a>`
`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myFunc()">Submit</a>`
Which is the appropriate one to use in my case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-should-i-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable HREF if onclick is executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622100/how-can-i-disable-href-if-onclick-is-executed)

Answer (score 1):

In JS development today none of those examples is really appropriate because inline JavaScript is pretty much frowned on - separation of HTML/JS is the best route to take.

So, in a separate JS file called from your HTML page (place the `<script>` just before `</body>` to ensure the DOM loads before the script is executed), grab your anchors, and add an event listener to each one that calls the corresponding function.

```
let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
[...anchors].forEach(anchor => anchor.addEventListener('click', handleAnchor, false));
```

Then in your function, make sure you pass in the event, and call `preventDefault()` to stop the disable the href.

```
function handleAnchor(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

MDN resources

- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks, @GetOffMyLawn.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, but not an Array so you can't call the array methods on it.

Comment: Apparently we're both right: "Only works in Blink browsers and Firefox 50+; no Safari or IE/Edge support"

Comment: What is `...buttons`? Shouldn't it be `...anchors`?