# How to prevent default navigation for Blazor NavLink component

Tags: c#, blazor

Since Blazor 3.1 Preview 2 it should be possible to [prevent default navigation behaviour](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-core-3-1-preview-2/) for links in Blazor, as also [discussed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59616455/1879019).

However, this code:

```html
<NavLink href="" Match="Match" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="()=>LinkAction()" >
Do something
</NavLink>
```

gives this error:

> The component parameter 'onclick' is used two or more times for this
>   component. Parameters must be unique (case-insensitive)

Why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although the net result of the HTML `<A>` tag and the Blazor `NavLink` component is the roughly the same thing, the `@onclick:preventDefault` syntax only works for the HTML version, not on Blazor components.

Steve Sanderson [explains this here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18460#issuecomment-577175682):

> I'm afraid there isn't a mechanism for passing through arbitrary
>   directive attributes such as @*:preventDefault as component
>   parameters, so this isn't expected to work on NavLink.

Steve also gives a possible solution:

> However, you could inherit your own subclass from NavLink that adds
>   the "prevent default" behavior. For example, create
>   NavLinkPreventDefault.razor, containing this:
>
> ```html
> @inherits NavLink 
> <a @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes" class="@CssClass" @onclick:preventDefault>
>     @ChildContent 
> </a>
> ```
>
> Now you can use  instead of  to get the 
>   behavior you want.

Comment: This has given me what I needed. I just changed the hard-coded preventDefault attribute to a parameter so it can be set dymanically: `@inherits NavLink <a @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes" class="@CssClass" @onclick:preventDefault="OnClickPreventDefault">@ChildContent</a> @code { [Parameter] public bool OnClickPreventDefault { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the parameter *href* and set a @onclick, it goes direct to the function and you can do as you please:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" @onclick="() => SetToActive(item)">
    <span class="pcoded-micon">
        <b class="fa-custom fas fa-bars @item.Icon"></b>
    </span>
    <span class="pcoded-mtext">@item.Title</span>
</NavLink>
```

This will call the method and there you can call the route:

```
private void SetToActive(CoolModel item)
{
    // do something...

    if (item.Route is not null)
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo(item.Route);
    }
}
```