# jquery ui / bootstrap dialog shown BEFORE an a href is clicked

Tags: jquery, redirect, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

Scenario is as follows:

I have a buch of `<a href="X">` elements so that, before the redirects happen, I want to wait for a bootstrap modal / jqueryui dialog (nevermined which, though I'd rather stick with the bootstrap modal) to be confirmed or canceled.
I have tried a sort of

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
   alert('!'); //this one of course happens before the redirect
   $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({...}); //this one shows and is immediately redirected
});
```

How could I accomplish my needs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37392990/2275490

Answer (score 0):

I managed it with:

```
$('.modal_before_click').on('click',function(e){

   redirect_after_modal =   $(this)[0]['href'];

   $('#modal_cancel_button').on('click',function(){window.location = redirect_after_modal;  });

   $('#modal_trigger_button').trigger('click');

   return false;
});
```