# Page reloads on click of a Link in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, jsx

I'm trying to show login and signup in just one page, that I can click on a login link that shows me the login form.

The problem is that when I click on the login **link**, `<a href="" onClick={() => setlogin(true)}>login?</a>`, the page gets loaded for 1s and then returns to sign up form.

**Code:**

```
import React, { ReactElement, Fragment, useState } from "react";

function LoginSignUp() {
  const [login, setlogin] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {login ? (
        <form className="form-signin">
          <input
            type="email"
            id="inputEmail"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Email address"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            id="inputPassword"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Password"
            required
          />
          <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <form className="form-signup">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="username"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Username"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Email address"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Password"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password2"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Confirm Password"
            required
          />
          <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
      )}
      <p id="logintxt">
        Do you already have an account? ,{" "}
        <a href="" onClick={() => setlogin(true)}>
          login?
        </a>
      </p>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable HREF if onclick is executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622100/how-can-i-disable-href-if-onclick-is-executed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop the default behavior of hyperlink which **refreshed** your page and component's `login` state data became `false` again:

**Option 1:**

```
function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  setlogin(true)
}

<a href="/" onClick={handleClick}>login?</a>
```

**Option 2:**

Or, you can use `#` as hyperlink placeholder, it won't refresh the page but will just append a `#` in browser URL. But it may give you [eslint warning that anchor is invalid](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md):

```html
<a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>login?</a>
```

**Option 3:**

Or, you can use a `span` or `button`:

```html
<span onClick={handleClick}>login?</span>

// OR

<button type="button" onClick={handleClick} class="btn btn-link">login?</button>
```

... and, make it look like a link using your or [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/) CSS.

Also, don't leave it blank `href=""`, it will take you to the current URL location but will still refresh your page.