# Redirect to other window JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm having problem in redirecting at JS.
Here's the situation:
the current directory of the html code is : `http://localhost:7927/MyWeb/Catch%20the%20bird%20game/GAME1.html`

I want to change the directory to

```
'http://localhost:7927/MyWeb/games.htm'
```

I tried using window.location("games.htm"); but it will redirect to that directory:

`http://localhost:7927/MyWeb/Catch%20the%20bird%20game/GAME1.html/games.htm`

What's the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
window.location("../games.htm");
```

or:

```
window.location("/MyWeb/games.htm");
```

Comment: The / infront of the file name tells the script to go to the root of the webserver and then find the document. Whereas if you don't add the / it'll search in the current folder :) That's what went wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
window.location.href = "/myweb/games.htm"
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
window.location = 'http://localhost:7927/MyWeb/games.htm';
```

or just this

```
window.location = '/MyWeb/games.htm';
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally use

```
window.location.href = ...
```

or

```
window.location.replace(...);
```

Also check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace).