# How do facebook style popup windows work?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to add popup windows to photo gallery. I used [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/) before. But there is one problem I think. JQuery uploads the window without opening new page. That means that you just have one page with pictures. I think it is not good for SEO. Facebook uses another way and when you open the photo, you have new url (but with parent page in background).

Could you explain how this stuff works? Are my thoughts about SEO right? Just for instance, I use django but I think it doesn't matter.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook uses both `href` and the attribute `ajaxify`.
When a link is clicked javascript will stop the link from gong to the other page and load the page specified in `ajaxify` to load the popup. If javascript isn't on then it will just follow the `href` to the photo page.

A facebook theatre anchor tag

```
<a class="uiMediaThumb _6i9 uiMediaThumbMedium" href="http://www.facebook.
    com/photo.php?loadandloadsofnumbers_n.jpg&size=720%2C960" aria-label="Photo"
    id="pic_nuuuuuumbers" rel="theater" ajaxify="http://www.facebook.com/photo.
    php?fbid=nuuuuuumbers&set=t.nuuuuuumbers&type=3&src=http%3A%2F%2Fsphotos-
    e.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash4%2F312300_10nuuuuuumbers54
    _773840764_n.jpg&size=720%2C960&theater">
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it's clear. Do you know how such windows work for SEO?

Comment: I can only imagine the regular href tag would be followed by Google allowing for a basic html site layout for SEO as well as for people with javascript disabled. I wouldn't have thought the extra 'theater' window would be included in any SEO related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.locaiton` to change the url to anything you want.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace) for a reference.