# Best way to show temporary processing page without adding to history in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We're trying to achieve the following story in MVC:

1. Customer hits a regular action/view page and fills out a form. They click the submit button to post the values back to the controller, which in turn starts a long-running background process.
2. Customer is redirected to a temporary 'processing - please wait' page. The page uses AJAX to periodically poll for a status update.
3. When processing has completed, redirect customer to the result page.

KEY REQUIREMENT: If the customer hits the Back button in the browser at step 3, they should return to step 1. We DO NOT want the customer to go to step 2 and we don't want step 2 to appear in the browser history.

How can we achieve the above without the dreaded "Resubmit Posted Values?" message too?

Please note that I'm not looking for a discussion on the pros/cons of polling here. I know it's not the best solution in the world and we may well refactor using Signal R. The story is the important thing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply apply the AJAX mechanism to step 1 (the page with the form) and use AJAX to POST the information back to the server and periodically poll the progress of the operation. You could dynamically hide/show the "Temporary Processing Page" using JavaScript without actually reloading the page.

Comment: Thanks. That's the option we are probably going to go with, other than the fact that we will need to handle form validation slightly differently.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps when going to the resullt page, you could use `window.location.replace (url);` ?

Basically it will replace the current history item therefore they can't get back to it.

See this discussion for more info: [window.location.replace (url);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which I found very helpful. Feels a bit 'dirty' though, fiddling with the browser history like that. Shame I can't achieve it naturally with HTTP/HTML.