# How to send a user to a different page using javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a "create an account" form with an age input. I have the age requirement set to 16. What I want to do is if the person is under the age of 16 it gives an alert message, and then when the user clicks the OK button on the alert window it sends them back to the index page.
Here is what I have for JS code:

```
if (age == null || age == "")
 {
 alert("Please enter your age to continue.");
 return false;
 }
else if (age == isNaN(age))
 {
 alert("Age input was not a number!\nPlease enter your age to continue.");
 return false;
 }
else if (age < 16)
 {
 alert("You are not old enough to have an account.\n If you have concerns or questions about our age policy please send them to ghost565xster@gmail.com.");
 return false;
 }
```

Basically when it runs that last "else if" statement and finds the input was less than 16, I want it to redirect the user to the index.html (Home) page after displaying the alert message.

I have tried using:

```
else if (age < 16)
{
 alert("You are not old enough to have an account.\n If you have concerns or questions about our age policy please send them to ghost565xster@gmail.com.");
 location.assign("index.html");
 return false;
 }
```

I have also tried location.href but neither work. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just in case anyone is wondering this "create account" for is on it's own html page named create.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [What's the difference between window.location= and window.location.replace()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace)

Best practice since you dont want them pressing back and getting in to a loop would be to use window.location.replace("sorryYouAreJustTooYoung.html");

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a new value to the `location` property. `location = "index.html"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 window.location.href = "your location";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post your html content too as you may have a problem there. I had this problem some time ago, when the age was under the required age limit i was directed to a site i never specified with the window.location.href.... even though it was assigned to a different site, the problem may be that you have wrapped an anchor tag around it so it will direct you to the site that you specified on your html page, i suggest you check that you dont have an anchor tab directing you elsewhere on your html page!

Answer (score -1):

easiest as possible:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```