# How to not keep history of html anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating an image slider in css3 with the :target selector. I have a next and previous button that are executing this line of javascript

```
window.location = "#image" + image;
```

The problem is that if i click the back button of my browser, it shows the previous image of the slider. I want the back button to go to the previous page, not the previous anchor.

Thanks for the help

Comment: soooo, why exactly is it you're changing the hashtag of the URL if you don't need the hashtag history?

Comment: well the most simple thing would be to stop changing the url, and find another way to slide the images

Comment: I agree with that, i will probably change it to a jquery slider instead of css3

Answer (score 4):

Use [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history):

```
history.replaceState({}, document.title, "#image" + image);
```

> history.replaceState() operates exactly like history.pushState() except that replaceState() modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one.
>
> replaceState() is particularly useful when you want to update the state object or URL of the current history entry in response to some user action.

Comment: @Marc-AndréTherrien sorry, I've missed it. I think there is no way to use `:target` avoiding browser history.

Comment: I don't think so either, i'll probably change the whole thing

Answer (score 4):

```
window.location.replace("#image" + image);
```

This does a simple redirect without adding it to the history.
MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.replace
Previous question: [What's the difference between window.location= and window.location.replace()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace)