# Back to page after redirection via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, browser

I have this problem.
Assume this navigation relation

```
Page 1---> Page 2---> Page 3
```

Suppose I am in Page 2. I arrive to Page 2 through a link `<a>` in Page 1. In Page 2, when I click on some elemen, I redirect the browser to Page 3 via JavaScript(`window.location.replace()`).
Now, in Page 3, if I click the back button  of the browser I go back to Page 1, while I was supposed to go back to Page 2.
I imagine that the problem is with the history of the browser.
Any help?

Comment: `window.location.*` is vanilla js, not jQuery.

Comment: This will solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace  don't use replace