# window.location.replace not working on localhost

Tags: javascript

I want to navigate to a URL on my site. This is what I have:

```
var TheDemoURL = window.location.host;

if (SomeCondition1) { TheDemoURL = TheDemoURL + '/fr/demo'; }
if (SomeCondition2) { TheDemoURL = TheDemoURL + '/de/demo'; }
...

window.location.replace(TheDemoURL);
```

Initially, in the variable watch, I have `TheDemoURL: "localhost:49173"` and when I alert the final `TheDemoURL` is looks a good URL but in reality nothing happens.

Why is this not working?

Comment: How are you triggering this? Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1865840/1470607), it's better to use `window.location.href`.

Comment: Still nothing happening; I think it has to do with the fact that it's currently running on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for those who come here, the solution was to add this:

```
var TheDemoURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
```

Not sure if this is specific to asp.net but it made it work.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.  However, I do still suggest that you use `self` here instead of `window` in order to ensure that things work correctly in case your site is even loaded in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
self.location = TheDemoURL;
```

This will take into account iframes and other weirdness.