# How to parse a string between tags into a URL, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, url

If I have an element on my page as such:

```
<a onclick="openUrl();">04-07-2014</a>
```

How can I retrieve the internal "04-07-2014" using javascript, so I can append it to the end of the URL? What would openUrl() have to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to give the [anchor element an id](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html):

```
<a onclick="openUrl();" id="a1" href="#">04-07-2014</a>
```

and retrieve the text of the anchor element in the `openUrl` function using the [document.getElementById function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById):

```
function openUrl(){
    var anchorElement = document.getElementById("a1");
    var url = "http://www.somewhere.net/" + anchorElement.textContent;
    alert(url);
}
```

The `openUrl` function could be written more succinctly (without the need of an id) using the [textContent or innerHTML property of a node](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/Node.textContent), in this case the anchor element, accessed via the [this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

```
<a onclick="openUrl(this.textContent);" href="#">04-07-2014</a>
```

and the code for the function:

```
function openUrl(p){
    var url = "http://www.somewhere.net/" + p;
    alert(url);
}
```

Both examples output `http://www.somewhere.net/04-07-2014`

In order to navigate to the new location use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location):

```
function openUrl(p){
    var url = "http://www.somewhere.net/" + p;
    window.location = url;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to know, why does it need the href="#"?

Comment: Because if your anchor element does not specify a `href` the text is not recognised as a link and the user can't click over it with the mouse. From W3 `If the HREF attribute is present, the anchor is sensitive text: the start of a link` - so if not defined it is not a sensitive link.

Comment: Nice solution. I did not know about the textContent property. But seems like IE8 doesn't support it :(. (What makes it unusable for many business applications)

Comment: You should also use `event.target` inside the event handler (`openUrl`) to get the actually clicked element. `getElementById` searches the DOM a second time, which is not necessary, as the event object has it stored internally. `p` in your second example should be an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object.

Comment: @L.Monty You are right. That is why I wrote textContent or innerHTML (for older browsers the `innerHTML` should work properly).

Comment: aah ok. I'm sorry, my fault...seems I should read more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

**Access the node-content by `innerHTML`-property of the *event.target***

You can make use of the `event.target` to get the currently clicked node and reading it's innerHTML. By using `window.location.href = ...;` you will get an similiar effect as clicking a link. You could also use `window.location.replace(..)` what will come the most close to a redirect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function openUrl(e){
            var url = 'www.baseUrl.com/';
            window.location.href = url + e.target.innerHTML;
     }
</script>
```

....

```
    <a  href="#" onclick="openUrl(event);">04-07-2014</a>
```

For closer information on the difference on `window.location.href = ..` vs `window.location.replace(..)` check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace)
 *(I am sure there are even better articles on SO about that...I remember reading a very good one)*

**EDIT:**
 I found the article i remembered: [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)