# How to use window.location.replace in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I have a website for which I have implemented livechat, when user clicks on livechat link it opens a new window that is fine. I want to do is when no operator is online then it should not open a new window when livechat link clicked instead it should redirect to the contact us page of the website in the same window in the currently opened tab, Is it possible?
I do not know how is it possible, what I have tried is this , it redirects to this page but opens in a new window.

```
window.location.replace('http://mywebsite.com/index.php?route=information/contact');
```

Comment: Why not `window.location = 'http://mywebsite.com/index.php?route=information/contact'` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between window.location= and window.location.replace()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace)

Comment: window.location does not work for me!

Comment: Micheal2's solution works for me and I did not find it anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is somewhere in the code around that. You need to call that code in the old window.

If you want to call it in the chat window, try:

```
window.opener.location.replace('http://mywebsite.com/index.php?route=information/contact');
window.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `href` property instead:

```
window.location.href = 'http://mywebsite.com/index.php?route=information/contact';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple javascript code like this: window.location.href = "SOME URL"
it will do the same think.            .