# React Router navigate to another page on radio button selection

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React Router and trying to navigate to another page on a radio button selection of "No". Please let me know if this is achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **change route** programmatically with history.push or history.replace - full documentation https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history. If you want to **navigate to another page**, you can do that with window.location.href - see question: [What's the difference between window.location= and window.location.replace()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) - since Redirect (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) cannot help in your case. Not sure which navigation you need (another route or page), but you can handle it inside of onChange event handler on your radio button.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class RadioButtons extends Component {
  state = { selectedOption: "" };

  handleOptionChange = e => {
    if (e.target.checked && e.target.value === "no") { // if value of "No" option is selected
      this.props.history.push("newRoute"); // navigate to another route
      //window.location.href = "https://www.google.com"; - if you want to navigate to another page
    }
    this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    const { history } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="radio">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              checked={selectedOption === "yes"}
              onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
            />
            Yes
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="radio">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="no"
              checked={selectedOption === "no"}
              onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
            />
            No
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or you can just put different onChange handler for radio button "No", to avoid checking is "Radio" button triggered or not.

```
<div className="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="no"
       checked={selectedOption === "no"}
       onChange={e => this.props.history.push('newRoute') || window.location.href= "https://www.google.com" }
     />
     No
   </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

You can see full code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/m3omno7olx
Hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic and complete answer! saved my day. Thanks! I did want to change route, just wasn't able to explain that very well.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help, have a great day! :)