# Redirect URL based on a value does not always work

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

I'm pretty new on JavaScript, I wrote a code to redirect user into another page based on what they typed in a search bar.

The weird thing is, it sometimes works sometimes don't (half half), someone might know what could cause this?

my HTML

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input id="inputName" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search"
           placeholder="Search">
    <button id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="searchUser()" type="button">
        Search
    </button>
</form>
```

my javascript

```js
function searchUser() {
    window.open("/user/" + String(document.getElementById('inputName').value));
}
```

---

Update: Thank you for point out dual id, I have deleted extra id but the issue remains.

It could happen to all string, eg., "hsy", it sometimes work, sometimes don't.

When searching from URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/hsy`, if it doesn't work, the URL just display as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/hsy?` with an extra question mark at the end of the URL.

Comment: You have 2 id's set for the `<input>` element.

Comment: Can you provide an example input for which it doesn't works?

Comment: `HTMLInputElement#value` is already a string. No need to convert it to a `String` object only to concatenate it to a raw string. You're just doing extra work for nothing XD

Comment: Oh yeah.. you have nothing stopping the form from doing its `default` behaviour of submitting the form. With no `action` attribute, it submits to the current URL, and with no `method` attribute, it defaults to `GET`. And since you have no `name` attributes on your form elements, the entire query is just... `?`. `<button type="button">` would be one way to solve that, although it's a bit strange to use a `<form>` when you aren't using any form-like behaviours.

Comment: @topsoftwarepro Hi, sorry your answer is not correct, the true reason is I mixed form with js. window.location.replace() seems not the reason :(

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work with `window.open()` because, if you read the console, it says: "there is a blocked opening 'stacksnippets.net/user/vfd' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set. window.open() works fine if it isn't in a Stack Snippet.". Because you were using StackSnippets or a similar frame to redirect. If you want to use it...

Use...

`window.location.replace()`

Instead of...

`window.open()`

```js
function searchUser() {
    window.location.replace("/user/" + document.getElementById('inputName').value);
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input id="inputName" class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="base_layout_user_search" type="search"
           placeholder="Search">
    <button id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="searchUser()" type="button">
        Search
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, mind explain why? they seem does not have much difference regarding the issue :( 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace/1865840

Comment: It doesn't work here because there is a blocked opening 'stacksnippets.net/user/vfd' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set. window.open() works fine if it isn't in a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Niet the Dark Absol, his idea is the truth.

I should not mix form with input. By delete form attribute it works as normal.

great thanks, fellows.