# JavaScript: Setting location.href versus location

Tags: javascript

When would you set `location` to a URL string versus setting `location.href`?

```
location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

vs

```
location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

[Mozilla Developer Network Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)

Comment: setting `location.href` mail fail because of same-origin-policy: http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy#can-t-get-but-can-set

Comment: Also, `replace` and `assign`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1865837/632951 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/7703689/632951 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/10302905/632951

Comment: I have an Angular 4 app that uses TypeScript 2.6.2. window.location is read only and I can only assign using window.location.href (in the context of a callback from an angular subscription), without compiler errors being reaised- maybe that's some kind of JavaScript 1.0 compatability thing or related to asynchronous handling. Basically window.location.href seems to be the only thing that always works.

Comment: Pertaining to the same-origin policy, note that the example you reference is within an iframe, so it might work differently when used on a normal page. Exact point of the page with the `location.href` policy: https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication#4q5rssu5ys

Answer (score 293, accepted):

You might set `location` directly because it's slightly shorter. If you're trying to be terse, you can usually omit the `window.` too.

URL assignments to both `location.href` and `location` are defined to work in JavaScript 1.0, back in Netscape 2, and have been implemented in every browser since. So take your pick and use whichever you find clearest.

Comment: Like mentioned by @SwissMister in the answer below, it seems that window.location.href is somewhat treated like an XHR request. If fired from within an XHR's success callback, window.location.href will be treated as an XHR while window.location emulates clicking on a link.

Answer (score 151):

Even if both work, I would use the latter.

Comment: While implementing a complex PayPal integration, I encountered a very compelling reason to use `window.location`: [it does not require `SAME ORIGIN`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy).

Comment: Maybe it's just me but `location = 'http://www.example.com'` seems super readable. Albeit, as a special case.  That is backwards compatible and [will remain compatible](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-location-interface) in the foreseeable future.

Comment: If window.location were an object, assigning a string to it would overwrite it with a string. In fact window.location is a property which has getter and setter methods. When you set it, a string is expected and the global Location object is updated by the setter. When you get it, the global Location object is returned.

Answer (score 65):

Like as has been said already. But, you will do better to use the `.href` version.

Comment: Good explanation, better than just general comments about readability or maintenance. In reality in this particular case the object model will not be changed, as half the web would halt - therefore use either... it doesn't matter which

Comment: This sounds good but isn't really true. There is no concept of a default property in the DOM or JavaScript in general. Assigning a string to `location` works because the property was defined to have this special assignment behaviour back in JavaScript 1.0 and every browser since has implemented that. HTML5 now requires it. So whilst it may be prettier or more consistent to assign to `.href`, there is no backward or forward compatibility advantage to doing so.

Comment: `window.location = url` is prettier

Comment: `location = url` is cuter

Comment: `location.href = url` is technically more correct and thus more safe (or fool-proof). In general, when you assign `myObject.someProp = someThing` you do not expect that the value of `someThing` will be assigned to `myObject.someProp.someInnerProp`, right? Then why would you expect it from `location.href`? It seems to be even dangerous to rely upon such behavior and assume that it will always work that quirky way.

Comment: Down voting for the same reason as given by @bobince

Comment: "location.href = url is technically more correct" No, it isn't. As most it's more *like the rest of Javascript*. But in fact `Location` is a well-defined object and the specs around it are clear and implemented consistently across the board. So `location = url` is equally correct. But shorter. And thus should, imho, be preferred in our perpetual quest to shave as much overhead off of our pages as possible.

Comment: `window.location.href = url` is stronger/smarter/bigger... =)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this stuff about default properties is incorrect and there is no such thing in JS. I'll undo my downvote if someone can link to some documentation for how to override `=` in JS.

Comment: This is the trashiest answer I ever saw on SO haha. Why not delete it? Almost everything has been crossed out

Answer (score 24):

A couple of years ago, `location` did not work for me in IE and `location.href` did (and both worked in other browsers). Since then I have always just used `location.href` and never had trouble again. I can't remember which version of IE that was.

Comment: It was probably that one version of IE where it did stuff wrong and every other browser did it correctly.  ;-)

Comment: in `strict mode` chrome will throw an exception if you try to assign directly to `location` too, so I always use `location.href`

Comment: "one" version of IE?

Comment: @Shawn D. A browser doing things correctly? When did that happen! :D

Comment: @Lpc_dark each one*

Answer (score 20):

One difference to keep in mind, though.

Let's say you want to build some URL using the current URL. The following code will in fact redirect you, because it's not calling [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) but [`Location.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace):

```
nextUrl = window.location.replace('/step1', '/step2');
```

The following codes work:

```
// cast to string
nextUrl = (window.location+'').replace('/step1', '/step2');

// href property
nextUrl = window.location.href.replace('/step1', '/step2');
```

Answer (score 16):

Just to clarify, you can't do `location.split('#')`, `location` is an object, not a string. But you can do `location.href.split('#');` because `location.href` is a string.

Comment: Your comment is true, but you are talking about _getting_ the href attribute, a string, of the location object. All the other discussions are dealing with _assigning_ a value, not reading the value. But your point is correct. The difference is that href is a string while location is an object.

Answer (score 11):

With TypeScript, use `window.location.href` as `window.location` is technically an object containing:

```
Properties
hash
host
hostname
href    <--- you need this
pathname (relative to the host)
port
protocol
search
```

Setting `window.location` will produce a type error, while
`window.location.href` is of type string.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13106968/6276704)

Answer (score 3):

Use `global.location.href` instead, while working with `React`.