# Is there any difference between window.location and window.location.href?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Javascript: Setting window.location.href versus window.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-window-location-href-versus-window-location)

When I tested these code in browser it seems like they are the same. Is there any difference?

## 1

```
window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

## 2

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: @Tim Oh, I couldn't find that.

Comment: No problem mate - sometimes its worth searching your question first - I just typed your title into the search and it was the first result.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.  `window.location` is a [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object) object.  `window.location.href` is a string representation of the location.  The `location` object's `toString()` value is the same as the `href` property, so they are identical if used as strings. Setting `window.location` is the same as setting `window.location.href`.

`window.location`, however, has several other properties you can use, such as `location.hostname`, `location.pathname` and `location.hash`.  So you could could set `location.hash` on its own to alter the hash value.

Comment: Here's a great reference on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#result

Answer (score 2):

[**windows.location**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location#Methods) adds an item to your history in that you can (or should be able to) click "Back" and go back to the current page. It is an Object.

On the other hand, `windows.location.href` is a string representation of `window.location`

Answer (score 2):

window.location is an object with some properties, but window.location.href is only string. In window.location you have for example reload method.