# What is the difference between window.location.href and location.href?

Tags: javascript

what is the difference if I put **window.location.href**  instead of **location.href** both of them seems to be returning the same value

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423513/is-there-any-difference-with-using-only-location-vs-using-window-location-across

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709037/window-location-versus-just-location?noredirect=1&lq=1; http://stackoverflow.com/q/6263073/2680216; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423513/is-there-any-difference-with-using-only-location-vs-using-window-location-across; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903659/difference-between-window-location-and-location-href

Comment: in Global context, all variables are assigned to window. So window.location===location . You may have a deeper look on *js global scope* + *js variable declaration*

Comment: Depending on the scope, yes