# Make table row clickable

Tags: jquery, html-table, click, row

I have a table row that has background color on hover. When user clicks within the background color area, it should grab the link of the anchor tag inside the row and take the user there.. How do I do this?

```
<tr id="ClickableRow">
    <td>
<a href="http://somesite.com">Go Here</a>
<p> To find about all the interestng animals found in this tourist attractions including 
zebra, giraffe.....
....
</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How do I grab the anchor tab href value ?

```
 $('tr #ClickableRow').click(function () {
         window.location.href=Anchor tag's href value

        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok first of all there's no need to specify a tr in the selector if you use an id anyway. 
And if you want to you should write that together without whitespace as the tr got that id.

Second, you need to use `this` and `find()` to select the first link inside the clicked table-row and get it's `href` attribute:

```
$('tr#ClickableRow').click(function () {
  var url = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

The following also works:

```
location = $(this).find('a:first').attr( 'href' );
```

See: [Javascript: Setting location.href versus location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2383401/59087)

Answer (score 2):

In your case

```
$('#ClickableRow').click(function () {
   window.location = $("#ClickableRow a:first").attr('href');
});
```

You can test on [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/4hdjL/).

To make it look like clickable you can add this

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#ClickableRow').hover(
    function () {
        if ($(this).find("th").length > 0) return;
        $(this).addClass("gridRowHover");
    },
    function () { $(this).removeClass("gridRowHover"); }
);
```

**CSS**

```
.gridRowHover{
    cursor: pointer;
 }
```

**Generic function**, to make any row of table clickable

```
function bindRowClick(itemId, eventHandler) {  
    var binder = "tr"; 
    $("#" + itemId).find(binder).click(eventHandler); 
}
```

`ItemId` will be your table id and `eventHandler` is the function to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
$('#ClickableRow').click(function () {
     window.location = $('a:first', this).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to also remove space between `tr` and `#ClickableRow` other wise it will take as children element.

```
$('tr#ClickableRow').click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
});
```