# How to make <tr> clickable as a link instead of cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

This must be a very easy and simple but i"m finding it hard to get it done.

I have a list of rows with 6 Column which shows data from mysql. I would like to make each row clickable instead of cell which opens a new url in new tab.

Here is the structure.

```
<tr> <a target="_" href="https://www.google.com">



<td style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 15px;">  </td>
<td><?php echo $row['district']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['program']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['yoa']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>


</a></tr>
```

Above Method Don't work.
Any Help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make table row clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981798/make-table-row-clickable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (without JS):

```html
        <tr>
        <td style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 15px;"></td>
        <td>
          <a href="http://google.com">
            <div style="height:100%;width:100%">
               1<?php echo $row['district']; ?>
            </div>
          </a>
        </td>
        
        <td>
          <a href="http://google.com">
            <div style="height:100%;width:100%">
              2<?php echo $row['program']; ?></td>
            </div>
          </a>
        <td>
          <a href="http://google.com">
            <div style="height:100%;width:100%">
              3<?php echo $row['gender']; ?>
            </div>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="http://google.com">
            <div style="height:100%;width:100%">
              4<?php echo $row['yoa']; ?>
            </div>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="http://google.com">
            <div style="height:100%;width:100%">
              5<?php echo $row['email']; ?>
            </div>
          </a>
        </td>
```

Comment: Don't do this unless you are not developing for the general population. Tabbing through will be a pain.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tr {
    position: relative;
}

tr a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will make anchor tag occupies the whole tr width and height, if needed, add `z-index` to `<a>`

Answer (score 1):

Remove tag "A"

and bind onClick event at "TR"

```
<tr onclick="_linkWhatYouWant" style="cursor: pointer;"> <td> ... blabla </td> </tr>
```

Comment: At least explain how to use jQuery's click(), or `addEventListener`. The use of `onclick` is just bad advice in 2019.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks Mike. You're right. I just give to him Hint. :-)

Comment: that's not what SO is for though. Don't just give hints, give answers =)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that this is not correct by the semantic point of view; However, you can set the `role=button` rule in your html.

```js
function navigateTo(url) {
  window.location.href(url);
}

document.querySelector('#row-1').addEventListener('click', function() { navigateTo('http://www.google.com/') });
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr:hover {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id='row-1' role='button'>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td>Item 5</td>
    <td>Item 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row-2' role='button'>
    <td>Item 7</td>
    <td>Item 8</td>
    <td>Item 9</td>
    <td>Item 10</td>
    <td>Item 11</td>
    <td>Item 12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and click function. This approach is simple and it gives you freedom to decide which rows are used as links. All you need to do is add a class and data attribute. You can also add `cursor:pointer` property in CSS.

```js
$('.click').click(function(){
     window.location = $(this).data('href');
     //use window.open if you want a link to open in a new window
});
```

```css
.click{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<tbody>
   <tr class="click" data-href="some-url-here">
       <th>1</th>
       <td>John Smith</td>
       <td>1-234-567-8900</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3hnt6mws/

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr data-link="https://www.google.com" data-target="_BLANK">
    <td>
      District
    </td>
    <td>
      Program
    </td>
    <td>
      Gender
    </td>
    <td>
      YOA
    </td>
    <td>
      Email
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("table tr").click(function(e) {
    var u = $(this).data("link");
    var t = $(this).data("target");
    console.log(u, t);
    if (t.length) {
      window.open(u, t);
    } else {
      window.location.href = u;
    }
  });
});
```

Using the `data` attribute, you can store more info with the row and use that in the `click` event. You can then programmatically direct the browser to open a new window or direct to a new location.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
The <tr> tag defines a row in an HTML table.

A <tr> element contains one or more <th> or <td> elements.

<table>
  <a href="www.google.com"><tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr></a>
  <tr>
</table>

try this will help you u can use <button> tag also to display like a button
```