# Difference between window.location and href?

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between this word and action?

```
<script>
window.location.href = 'index.php';
window.location = 'index.php';
</script>
```

because some instances that after clicking the button there is a milisecs thats see the way of changing the page..what is that?

Comment: In case of assignment, there is no difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differenece between window.location and location.href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903659/differenece-between-window-location-and-location-href)

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href` returns the location of the current page while `window.location` returns a Location object, which contains information about the URL of the document and provides methods for changing that URL. You can also assign to this property to load another URL.

[Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

Comment: thanks bro this will help thank you so much i just want to clarify my self :)