# How to redirect to next page if password is correct JavaScript

Tags: html

```
 <form class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="input-field" placeholder="Username" required>
            <input type="password" id="input-field2" placeholder="Password" required>
            <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" onclick="op()">Login</button>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
function op(){
     var field2=document.getElementById("input-field2").value;
    if(field2==="Bishesh")
        window.location="html.html";
        
    
     else{
         alert("invaild information")
    }
}  
   
</script>
```

I tried a lot but it is not redirecting. Please help. It is not redirecting to another page. If you can solve this problrm then please help me

Comment: This is just for practice is it? It is totally insecure

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? Is the form submitted before the page can redirect?

Answer (score 0):

`document.location.href='./page.html'`

Comment: What is the problem and how does your code help solve it? See [What's the difference between window.location and document.location in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascrip/2431375) and [Difference between window.location and location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903659/difference-between-window-location-and-location-href).