# window.location vs window.location.href vs window.location.assign()

Tags: javascript

Redirection is possible using

```
window.location = '<url>'
window.location.href = '<url>'
window.location.assign('<url>')
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between window.location and location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903659) **and** [Difference between window.location.href, window.location.replace and window.location.assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703689) **and** [location.href property vs. location.assign() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302905)

Comment: @adiga—you can add multiple duplicates using the *edit* link. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I don't see it when I edit. Only gold badges?

Comment: @adiga—dunno, it's a mystery to me… ;-)

Comment: @RobG couldn't find any meta post on adding multiple dupes. So, I think it's available only to those with the *hammer* :)

Comment: @adiga—fixerated…