# Set window.location with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am getting an error with the following TypeScript code:

```
 ///<reference path='../../../Shared/typescript/jquery.d.ts' />
 ///<reference path='../../../Shared/typescript/jqueryStatic.d.ts' />

 function accessControls(action: Action) {
    $('#logoutLink')
        .click(function () {
            var $link = $(this);
            window.location = $link.attr('data-href');
        });

 }
```

I am getting an underlined red error for the following:

```
$link.attr('data-href');
```

The message says:

```
Cannot convert 'string' to 'Location': Type 'String' is missing property 'reload' from type 'Location'
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

`window.location` is of type `Location` while `.attr('data-href')` returns a string, so you have to assign it to `window.location.href` which is of string type too. For that replace your following line:

```
window.location = $link.attr('data-href');
```

for this one:

```
window.location.href = $link.attr('data-href');
```

Comment: I note that in browsers today, setting `window.location = "some string"` has special behaviour, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-location-href-versus-location - see the comments regarding same-site, same-origin and XHR behaviour.

Comment: While implementing a complex PayPal integration, I noticed a very compelling reason to use `window.location`, instead of `window.location.href`: [it does not require `SAME ORIGIN`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy).

Answer (score 44):

you have missed the `href`:

Standard, To  use `window.location.href` as `window.location` is technically an object containing:

```
Properties
hash 
host 
hostname
href    <--- you need this
pathname (relative to the host)
port 
protocol 
search
```

try

```
 window.location.href = $link.attr('data-href');
```

Answer (score 7):

There's an `assign` method on the Location interface that plays perfectly well with typescript when passed a string and works the same as `window.location = LOCATION`.

```js
window.location.assign('http://example.com');
```

```js
interface Location {
    ...
    /** Navigates to the given URL. */
    assign(url: string | URL): void;
}
```

The method seems to have be around for a long time (IE 5.5!).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign

Answer (score 3):

While implementing a complex PayPal integration, I noticed a very compelling reason to use `window.location`, that
[it does not require `SAME ORIGIN`](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication).

Hence we did something like:

```
(<any> window).location = myUrl;
```

Instead of:

```
window.location.href = myUrl;
```

> Where in OP's case:
>
> ```
> var myUrl = $link.attr('data-href');
> ```

Answer (score -3):

Just add href

Like this:

```
window.location.href = $link.attr('data-href');
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13106955/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*