# Getting error: 'Cannot assign to 'location' because it is a constant or a read-only property' with mailto function in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mailto

I am trying to set up a function in my Angular 2 app that will send an email using the user's default email client with some pre-populated info:

```
sendEmail() {
    this.title = document.title;
    this.title = this.title.replace("&", "-");
    window.location = "mailto:?body=" + this.title + " - " + window.location + "&subject=I thought this link might interest you.";
}
```

But I'm running into an issue where I'm getting an error:

> Cannot assign to 'location' because it is a constant or a read-only
>   property. webpack: Failed to compile.

The examples I've seen so far all describe doing it thie way, with "window.location", so how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106950/set-window-location-with-typescript

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're missing the `href`

```
window.location.href = ....
```

You can also do this with the Angular `Router` by giving it a static url:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('url')
```