# Refreshing the page with java script but I want to post something to refreshed page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am in sort of a pickle right now. I am trying to refresh my java page but I want to post some new data to it. But the issue is I don't know where to start. All I know is the location.reload() is there a way I can do a location reload but send new data to the refreshed paged?

Edit: Sorry I got this wrong. I have a script that always has a different url so I cant just do the new location to 'http ://...../' so I need a way I can pass values without that

Comment: With QueryStrings? `?data=newdata`

Comment: Just make a form with the action to the same page?

Comment: can we have some better context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

1. use `window.location.href = '/your-url?param1=value&etc=...'` to send data as query string
2. create a form with your url as the action, add fields and then submit it (this makes it possible to submit your data using POST)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways are there:

```
1. window.location.href = 'http://www.yoursite.com?data1=val1&data2=val2';

2. window.location = 'http://www.yoursite.com?data1=val1&data2=val2';
```

1st method is always suggested as best practice. Refer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-window-location-href-versus-window-location)