# How to redirect page on form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

I have a form that I would like to submit. Once done redirect the page to another. However currently it is not working for me.

```
<form name="myname" method="post" action="actionurl" onsubmit="gotonext()">

function gotonext(){
            var portalpath = window.location.pathname;                              
            var myredirect =  portalpath +"?uP_fname=msu/survey&amp;command=display&amp;sid=162";
            alert(myredirect);
            window.location.href = myredirect;
        }
```

So the alert displays the correct url that I am seeking to go to. And the form submits the data to the correct actionurl. What is not working is the redirect.

Any ideas on where I might be going wrong?

Comment: `Currently the page loads the actionurl (which is another page)` ??

Comment: the actionurl is a base-url in a portal. It simply returns to the portal page instead of redirecting. I tried to simplify the question. Sorry if confusing, will edit that.

Comment: @Sébastien http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-window-location-href-versus-window-location

Comment: @user1689274 have you tried using a redirect header in your actionurl page?

Comment: window.location = myredirect;  Did not work either.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan So it is, my bad.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Can't edit there, that actionurl receives other forms as well.

Comment: @user1689274 than just put a `"&redirectto="+myredirect ` in your *getter* and read it in your *actionurl* page inside an `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a bit more complicated. The problem is when the form is submitted, the client basically already starts processing a new request by URL specified in the form's `action` attribute.

One usual workaround is to use AJAX to submit the form, then trigger the redirect in that AJAX request's callback. That's easier, but has obvious limitations: AJAX requests won't cross domains.

Another approach (that might be useful in your case) is the following:

- create a hidden iframe on the page with the form.
- set the form's `target` attribute to that iframe's name
- set `onload` event handler on this iframe, and trigger redirect in this handler.

Here's [proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/rTrT6/).

Comment: A Similar idea hit me last night, I will either do something like this, or add the link to the desired location as a hidden element on the page, then trigger a click with jquery, or use ajax...Thanks for the answer. and Thanks @RokoC.Buljan for the help as well