# Javascript/Jquery open relative page in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am on

```
www.foo.com
```

how to call javascript or jquery to navigate to

```
www.foo.com/site1
```

or if I am on `www.foo.com/site1` to go on

```
www.foo.com/site1/site2
```

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: are you using any button clicks or anchor clicks to achieve this

Comment: no clicks, just pure js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "/site1"
```

I suppose this would work.

Answer (score 1):

to get inside site1 from outside

```
window.location.href="site1/";
```

to get inside site1/site2 if you are inside site1

```
 window.location.href="site2/";
```

to get inside site1/site2 directly if you are "outside"

```
window.location.href="site1/site2/";
```

to get out of site1 if you are inside site1

```
window.location.href="../";
```

to get out of site1/site2 if you are inside site1/site2

```
window.location.href="../../";
```

to get out of site1a if you are inside site1a and into site1b (at same level)

```
window.location.href="../site1b/";
```

Of course you do not need javascript for this if you use links like `<a href="../site1b/">GO</a>` to click.

Using just window.location=.. works too (has even broader support) and even location=.. (you can omit "window.", but I wouldn't do it for clarity and maybe compatibility)

[Javascript: Setting location.href versus location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-window-location-href-versus-window-location)

I used all paths with trailing "/", being folders, to avoid automatic redirects from "site1" to "site1/" (slightly slower).

Answer (score 0):

This will trigger it

`window.location.href="url/goes/here";`