# How do I use jQuery to redirect to a clicked TR in a dynamically-created table?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have jQuery code that works beautifully for clicking a row in a table that exists at page-load and getting redirected to a new page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#myTable").on('click','tr',function() {
  var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  if(href) 
  { window.location = href; } 
 }); 
});
```

I have a second table that gets generated by a jQuery POST and is added dynamically and I know it works because I can alert() myself when I click on a row of a dynamically-created table:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myDynamicTable tr', function(e) {
 var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
 alert(href); 
 });
```

Obviously, href is undefined. So what code can I use to replace the alert() line with an actual redirect to the link that's in that particular TR?

Update with HTML code:
A sample HTML code that is returned via POST to the main page where the user clicks TRs:

```
<table id='myDynamicTable' border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
<tr><a href="http://address.com/page.php"></a><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><a href="http://address.com/page.php"></a><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Again, the only difference between this dysfunctional table row clicking and other tables on the same page is the fact that myDynamicTable is generated dynamically via jQuery based on a search string put into an input type="Text" by the user.

Comment: I hope there is a `td` that holds that `a` right ? (a.k.a can we see the html + generated html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the browser URL, just set `window.location`:

Presumably your have anchors inside `TD`s inside your `TR`s (you should show sample HTML too).

```
$(document).on('click', '#myDynamicTable tr', function(e) {
     var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
     window.location = href; 
 });
```

Technically you are meant to set `window.location.href`, but all browsers allow the shortcut. [Javascript: Setting location.href versus location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-window-location-href-versus-window-location)

Comment: Yes, that's all I'm trying to do. Unfortunately, using this code, href is "undefined." Any idea why it would be considered undefined?

Comment: It would be easier to answer that question, and help, if we could see HTML.

Comment: Oh, and good point! 

Yes, each row inside my `<table id='myDynamicTable'>` table is of the structure:

`<tr><a href="URL"></a><td></td></tr>`

This works perfectly for existing tables that exist at time of page-loading, just not for tables that are generated dynamically for some reason..

Comment: I updated the original post to show the HTML that gets inserted into the page dynamically.

Comment: WOW. Weird how it works one way for existing tables and another way for dynamic ones! 
Simply moving the `<a>` tag inside of the `<td>` tag makes all the difference. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

User This

```
    <table id='myDynamicTable'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="google.com">redirect to</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

your jquery code is true

```
 $(document).on('click', '#myDynamicTable tr', function(e) {
 var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

    window.location=href;
 });
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, but when I alert(href), it just tells me it's undefined. I've double- and triple-checked for typos, but there are none. 

Any other ideas?

The table is generated dynamically, if that helps.

Comment: Yes. That code works perfectly on a statically-defined table that exists when the page is loaded, but it's not working for my dynamically-generated table that is generated based on user interaction with the page. 

Is there something special you have to do/include when working with dynamic content?

I cannot help but notice that when I view the page source, the dynamic table is not shown even though it's on my screen.

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#myDynamicTable tr', function(e) {}) this function for dinamic created element in dom but $('#myDynamicTable ').click() this function for static element, plesae send me your html in after loade page  inspect element ok?

Comment: That's three times you've given me the same code... that I've already tried... that doesn't work. But thank you for your help! :)

Comment: So, in order for it to work properly, the anchor tags must be placed inside of the `<td>` instead of the `<tr>`, then?