# HTML Autocomplete opens a webpage when pressing enter

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete page which gives me a text value, but I want the same text value to open a webpage when hitting enter or selecting the suggested value.

E.g. when I search for india, I type "ind" and "india" automatically comes up, but and I want "india" to open a webpage (like "domain.com/india") when selecting the value or hitting enter

The code is as follows:

```
<datalist id="countries">
    <select>
        <select id="dynamic-select">
        <option value="www.blahblah.com">Blah</option>
        <option value="www.something.com">something</option>
<script>
    $('#dynamic-select').bind('change', function () { // bind change event to select
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
        if (url != '') { // require a URL
            window.location = url; // redirect
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
</datalist>
```

It pulls out the value but it doesn't open a webpage for me. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to add that here but i already have it on my page so that part is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
window.location = url;
```

To

```
window.location.href= url;
```

Comment: They're equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-location-href-versus-location

Answer (score 0):

You need to use correct URL syntax. You're missing the `//` prefix, so it's treating the URL as a filename on your website, not the address of another website.

```js
$('#dynamic-select').bind('change', function() { // bind change event to select
  var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
  if (url != '') { // require a URL
    window.location = url; // redirect
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dynamic-select">
  <option value="">Please choose</option>
  <option value="//www.blahblah.com">Blah</option>
  <option value="//www.something.com">something</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried that it pulls out the value as //www.website.com but dosnt open up that page

Comment: Did you run my example? When I select `something`, it opens up that page.

Comment: Yes i tried the same. Dint work :(. what it does is it gives me the link with "//" in that box as an output. it looks like "//www.google.com" but dosnt do anything alse. i actually copied the same u sent to be sure i i am doing something wrong

Comment: Are there any messages in the Javascript console?

Comment: I tried it in both Chrome and Firefox on OS X, it worked in both.

Comment: So when you select "something", the page doesn't change to show "Something."?

Comment: Yesy thats correct rather it only shows //www.somthing.com in the box as an output. FYI there are some .js script associated to it too can i send the whole thing somewhere where you can see how i have it compiled?

Comment: I don't see how that can be. There's nothing in my answer that puts the value of the select into the output box.

Comment: All I can think of is that you have a browser extension that's doing something weird. Try disabling extensions and running my snippet.

Comment: FYI there are some .js script associated to it too can i send the whole thing somewhere where you can see how i have it compiled?

Comment: Can you post a link I can access?

Comment: No im afraid. I dont have that priviledge as of now

Comment: i have that elaborated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252298/need-help-for-autocomplete-to-open-a-webpage-from-value-in-the-text-box