# Javascript Redirect sends visitors to Wrong URL

Tags: javascript, redirect, permalinks

I have a redirect that happens after a user submits a form.  Users should move through the funnel like this:

SiteA.com/submit-form/  --->  SiteB.com/payment/

Problem - The redirect ignores the domain name (i.e. SiteB).  It sends visitors to SiteA.com/payment/

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
        var linkerParam = tracker.get('linkerParam');
                 var url = 'https://siteB.com/payment/?' + linkerParam;
        window.setTimeout(window.location = url, 4000);
    });
```

This code is meant to append Google Analytics cross-domain tracking code.  The form plugin (Formidable Pro) also has a redirect option built-in.  When activated, it also redirects to the wrong page.

I'm not sure where to start looking.  I had added a Category Base in Permalinks.  I've just removed it, hoping this might be the problem.  Any ideas / help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried http instead of https?

Comment: the first argument of `setTimeout` should be a function. also check the console for errors.

Comment: Whats siteb.com? May it has enabled a strict CORS policy

Answer (score 0):

window.location return object and in strict mode you will get exception in Chrome.
Full explanation you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-location-href-versus-location)

You just need

`window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = url}, 4000);`