# How to Redirect Success or Failure Payment in Razorpay

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway

I am New to Integrate Payment Gateway.

How to Redirect a URL after Success or Failure Payments in Razorpay. I want Js Code. I thing handler function can use that redirect. How to Use them

```
var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_aIfnpuWEudWnID",
    "amount": "35000", // 2000 paise = INR 20
    "name": "Vanakkam Chennai",
    "description": "I Run.. Becasue .. I Care",
    "image": "http://vanakkamchennai.com/images/about/chennai_2017.jpg",
    "callback_url": 'https://www.google.com',
    "handler": function (response){

            alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);


    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "Harshil Mathur",
        "email": "harshil@razorpay.com"
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Hello World"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
    }
};
```

Comment: if the transaction is failure , the handler is not called..how do i call the handler in case of failure ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way to redirect a user is to alter the value of `location.href`.  Remove `alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);` and redirect the user based on if the payment id is defined or not:

```
// alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
if (typeof response.razorpay_payment_id == 'undefined' ||  response.razorpay_payment_id < 1) {
  redirect_url = '/you-owe-money.html';
} else {
  redirect_url = '/thnx-you-paid.html';
}
location.href = redirect_url;
```

My example urls are humorous; replace them with your actual urls.  Also, you can read more detailed information on [location.href and location redirection here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-location-href-versus-location).

Comment: can we have any action over else part ?

Comment: @godwin yes! you can have _any_ action in the `else` block! let your creative juices flow!

Comment: but other application  parts out of the razorpay option variable is not accessible in the `else` part , it allows only redirection , so i achieved my need only after redirection

Comment: i really don't have any suggestions for you; but, if it were me, i would `console.log(response)` and go from there.  i am glad that you achieved your need, even if only after redirection.

Comment: How to do this in PHP laravel please suggest something

Comment: @anaya this is client side code...so, php laravel being server side code would mean that this would work for you. perhaps you should open a question with details.

Comment: if the transaction is failure , the handler is not called..how do i call the handler in case of failure ?

Comment: @sathyanarayanangvk i think you can open a new question with an appropriate snippet of code; i would also encourage you to reference this SO. imho, _comments_ are a poor place to receive assistance that invariably will be more intricate than your everyday tweet.

Comment: understood..will do the same @WEBjuju