# Redirect changing page URL but not rendering new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a page that validates a user and redirects them to a login page if validation is successful. However, the using `redirect` the URL changes but the new page for `Login` is not rendered. How can I get the new page to render?

App.js

```
var child;

render() {
if (this.state.toLogin && !this.state.mounted) {
    <Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} />;
    <Route exact strict path="/" render={({location}) => {
       if (location.pathname === window.location.pathname) {
             return <Redirect to="/Login"/>;
        }
    return null;
}}

return(
    <div className="App">
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName="remove"
            transitionEnterTimeout={100}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={100}>
                {child}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

EDIT: Made changes as per answers but now the URL is not changing and the page is not rendering

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-rb2cvc?file=index.js this works as expected, can you show what is your problem?

Comment: how do you assign a value to `var child`? Can you show full codebase of `App`?

Comment: checkout my answer @black

Comment: It turns out I wasn't rendering things properly but appreciate all the answers

Comment: If you came to this question because you're trying to redirect to an external page, this question is what helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link/44563899#44563899

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using `react-router-dom` wrap your component export in `withRouter` provided by `react-router-dom` .

and all component usage should be returned from render. then only react knows what to render.

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {

render() {
if (this.state.toLogin && !this.state.mounted) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} /> 
      <Route exact strict path="/" render={({location}) => {
          if (location.pathname === window.location.pathname) {
              return <Redirect to="/Login"/>;
          }
          return null;
      }} />
  </React.Fragment>
  );
}

return (
  <div className="App">
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="remove"
        transitionEnterTimeout={100}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={100}>
            {child}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
</div>
)}

}
export default withRouter(App)
```

Comment: Undoubtedly, your answer is correct. this was my damn issue too and `withRouter` help me. but I don't know why, Why the `withRouter` HOC fix this issue?

Comment: @AngelHotxxx, I have mentioned in my answer why withRouter solves the problem, you can check it

Comment: @AngelHotxxx for `react-router-dom` it needs some routing related props. which are used to change the browser route and add url to history object etc. that are given by this `withRouter` HOC

Answer (score 0):

You need remove "exact" and "component={Login}" of the Component  and add new Component `<Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} />`

```js
render() {
  if (this.state.toLogin && !this.state.mounted) {
      <Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} /> 
      <Route exact strict path="/" render={({location}) => {
          if (location.pathname === window.location.pathname) {
               return <Redirect to="/Login"/>;
          }
          return null;
  }} />
}
```

Luck!

Comment: I tried the change but I still don't see the page rendering. I've added the entirety of the `App.js` in case something is interfering

Answer (score 0):

Do not do that here, Use your authentication middle ware to do re directions according to the authorization/ rights.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a couple of returns. Your render function has to return your routes, and your routes have to be wrapped on some element.

```
  render() {
    if (this.state.toLogin && !this.state.mounted) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} /> 
          <Route exact strict path="/" render={({location}) => {
              if (location.pathname === window.location.pathname) {
                  return <Redirect to="/Login"/>;
              }
              return null;
          }} />
      </React.Fragment>
      );
    }

    return //Something according to your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "component" and "path" keyword in route tag should be in Small Letter(component instead for Component

Answer (score -1):

In order for the Routes to works, the component which uses Route must receive the Route parameters

In your case the App component doesn't seem to receive the Route parameters as props. You could simply render it as a default Route or use `withRouter` HOC to wrap the App component

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route component={App} />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you do not return your routes. Try moving your routes to the place where you are initializing your router and wrap it with App:

```
<Router>
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} />;
    <Route exact strict path="/" render={({location}) => {
       if (location.pathname === window.location.pathname) {
         return <Redirect to="/Login"/>;
       }
       return null;
    }/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

And then in your App component just use children to render page content:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="remove"
          transitionEnterTimeout={100}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={100}
        >
                {this.props.children}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
```