# How to Redirect to a new page like www.google.com in ReactJS like click a button window.location.href

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hallo I am new to React and here.

I have questiona about redirect to an URL in React.  I am wondering if I can make React page redirect to another URL like www.google.com
I did it like .

```
<a href='http://localhost:8000/api?issuer=ideal_KNABNL2H'>Go to Pay</a> 
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">
```

But it doen't work at React.
Can it be done in react-router? I have read its doc, still don't know how to make it.

Comment: why not use a normal link  like `<a href="http://www.google.com">go to google</a>` ?

Comment: Also in reactjs you have to capitalize the C in onClick

Comment: Have you checked out these previous questions and answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link

Answer (score 2):

You don't need react for this :)

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/"><button>Visit google</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me

```
<button onClick={() => window.open( 'http://www.google.com')} >google</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href={https://www.google.com}>Google!</a>
```

Make sure you just include "**https://**" before the website. I'm also new to react here, and was having trouble when I wrote only "**www.google.com**". It was adding that to the end of my URL instead of redirecting to Google's website.

Comment: I'd just note that this isn't a React thing, but a HTML one.

Answer (score -2):

```
<MyLink link="http://www.google.com" title="Google"/>
```

If it is to redirect to another page, enter http, but if it is to access screen in the project it is used React Router

> npm install react-router-dom