# Links to external resource are empty in React

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

In a `React` app I have a `Table` `tbody` of which looks the following way:

```
<tbody>
                        {
                        this.state.datasets.map((datasetName, idx) => {
                          return (<tr>
                            <td>
                              <div className={"pretty p-default p-curve"}>
                                <input id = {"datasetCheckBox" + idx}
                                  checked = {this.state.checkBoxSelected === datasetName}
                                  type="radio" name="datasetName"
                                  onChange={(e) => this.checkBoxSelected(datasetName, e)}/>
                                  <div className={"state p-primary"}>
                                     <label>{idx}</label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>{datasetName}</td>
                            <td>{datasetsJSON["datasets"][datasetName]["region"]}</td>
                            <td>{datasetsJSON["datasets"][datasetName]["authors"]}</td>
                            <td>
                              <a href={datasetsJSON["datasets"][datasetName]["link"]}>{datasetName}</a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>)
                        }, this)
                      }
                      </tbody>
```

The link is shown with an empty `href` even though other parameters of the table from `datasetsJSON["datasets"][datasetName]` are set correctly. I tried using `React Router` and the only piece of code that redirected to links is in the answer here:

[React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

But in the answer to the question above if I set `path="/"`, when the table loads, it is just redirecting me straight away to the first link. I would expect then that for each link the `path` should be different, but supplying `datasetsJSON["datasets"][datasetName]["link"]` as a `path` does not work either. Why is the simple link `a` empty? How could I fix it?

Comment: Are you able to print out the link as text above outside of the a tag like so {datasetsJSON["datasets"][datasetName]["link"]}

Comment: Also.  For sanity check can you console.log the whole datasets.JSON["datasets"][datasetName] object?

Comment: Sure, prints out nicely the correct urls. Also the link is inside the modal if it can be of importance here, although I doubt it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `onClick` method instead of `href` link attribute. In the table I have:

```
<td onClick = {() => this.articleClicked(datasetName)}>
     <span role="button"><a>{datasetName}</a></span>
</td>
```

Then, `onClick` method:

```
  articleClicked = (datasetName) => {
    let url = datasetsJSON["datasets"][datasetName]["link"];
    window.open(url);
  }
```

`<span role="button">` is needed for the cursor to show hand when the user is hovering over the link. It is `bootstrap` thing.