# How to route to different app with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, vue.js

I'm developing a user management system using React. Hosted on Firebase and using Firebase realtime database.
( let's assume this a.firebaseapp.com)

The current system uses react-router to handle routing menus.
After system administrator logs in, create a session and navigate to appropriate menu.

```
<Route key="app" path="app/:uuid" component={App} onEnter={onRequireAuth} /> />
```

A new version of system has been developed using new UXs and new database(firestore) ( this is vue.js app ). This new system is hosted on new Firebase ( assume this b.firebaseapp.com )

After admin logs in to the current system, will route to a new system ( vue app ) or current system ( react app ) by determining some conditions.

`logs in to react app -> check condition -> react app (a.firebaseapp.com) / vue app (b.firebaseapp.com)`

Login page is included in current react app.

I have separate Firebase hosting with different domain, can I move between different domains with react-route?

I don't think this is easy, but do readers have any good ideas to deal with this situation?

Comment: No you cannot do that with react-router. I think you have to pass necessary parameters to other app with url parameters or by using firebase storage.

Comment: I added some module to link external app url with this sample https://stackoverflow.com/a/42988282/8861167 :) @mstfyldz

Comment: You are redirecting to other app with url parameters. Route works perfectly with react. window.location is the key point in this answer because redirecting is done with this, not by router!