# Anchor tag redirects to react spa

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, anchor

I want to use an anchor tag in my react spa (using react-router). But if I give it, for example, an `href` value of `google.com`, it will just extend my spa route, to say `myreactspa.com/sampleRoute/google.com`. Is there any way to make my anchor tag directly link to [google.com](https://google.com)? Or must I append, for example, `https://` to my `href` value? Thanks!

Comment: Seems to have been answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Route` component rendering `null` and change the window's location.

```
<Route path='/externalresource' component={() => { 
     window.location.href = 'http://google.com'
     return null
}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append `https://` to your URL and set the `target` attribute of the `a` tag to `_blank`. It is not a problem of React Router to handle external links.

So something like that:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com target="_blank">Link</a>
```

**There is no need to try use React Router to handle external links**

Answer (score 0):

react-router (and similar) is specially designed for SPA. When you are trying to navigate to another website (external link), the router is not supposed to handle that. If you are using `Link`, then whatever path you pass, react-router assumes that to be a route of your SPA (this is expected behaviour, NOT a bug).

If you want to navigate to another website from your web-app, use plain anchor tag like this

`<a href="website_link">Click here</a>`

If you want to open the page in a new tab use

`<a href="website_link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Click here</a>`