# Redirect to an html page if the route isn't specified

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm looking to have a redirect for every link that aren't specified in the configuration of my react app. The small difference with other tutorial is that I want to redirect to an html page which is present in my public folder and not a react component.

Something like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={component}/>
    <Redirect  to="/404.html"/>
</Switch>
```

but it creates an infinite loop if I enter anything else than mysite/ and mysite/404.html. If i type mysite/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

it returns the following error : Maximum update depth exceeded

Any idea why it happens and how I can solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t just point to an external link with React Router. The library defaults to route navigation within your app.

This has your answer:

[React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a route with no path specified like that:

```
<Route component={NotFound} />
```

and create a NotFound component that renders a not found message or redirect to an external page if you prefer