# How can I redirect to external link at react server-side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-dom

I've a situation where I want to route to external site at server-side in my single-page application. I want to redirect at certain condition when my data fetching throws particular status code.

What I've tried -

1. I could intercept response in the Express middleware using res.statusCode. This is 500 due to any error in code and I can't distinguish the reason at this time.
2. I tried using `<Redirect>` from `react-dom-router` but this seems like doesn't work for external links.

Can you suggest any way to redirect to external link during server-side rendering?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

Comment: I read this. This suggests  window.location but this is possible at client side and not server-side.

Comment: You can make redirect using http or any framework (koa, express for example)

Comment: I learn whether to redirect or not while rendering, and express would know only res.status as 500. The actual reason when I want to redirect is when component is rendered.