# Redirecting to an external link using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563899/5049813) for redirecting to an external link, and it has worked for one of my pages.

But for a different page it is no longer working, and I'm not sure why.

`redirect.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Redirect extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Route path='/hello' component={() => {
            window.location.href = "example.com";
            return null;}}/>
        );
    }
}
```

`test.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import MainExport from './components/redirect.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <MainExport />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById("content")
);
```

`test.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div className="App">
        <div id="content" />
    <div/>
    <script src="dist/bundle/test.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I load this page, I expect it to redirect to the URL "/hello" and display the page from "example.com".

Instead, it does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Some of the answers have been helpful, but none of them have worked yet.

I've found that using the `Redirect` component renders and does the redirect, but does it in some way such that my Flask server doesn't actually serve the file. All I see is a blank screen.

Changing the name to `MyRedirect` also did not make it work.

Using `render` instead of `component` also did not seem to have an impact.

**The redirect is still not taking place.**

(I'm also still not seeing any error messages in the JS console or on the server side.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create your own Redirect component if you're using react-router. They [already](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) made one for you.

You just need to import it and render it to be redirected.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

export default () => <Redirect to="/hello" />
```

Comment: I think this works if I'm handling an internal redirect. But I want it to be handled as an external redirect. If I use this, I expect to see a 404 error but instead see a blank page. If I refresh the page afterwards, then I see the default flask 404 error page.

Comment: What do you mean when you say handled as an external redirect? If the page isn't on your site you can just use `http://www.othersite.com/hello"` in the `to`

Comment: I believe if I give React a relative link, react router tries to render a component, rather than contacting the website. I’m not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. The router handles the routes as the name says xDDDD but with in the scopes if the usaw is going to get out of the scope of the app. Add the anchor tags in the button the user is going to click.

Note: they should be “a” tags for those a that targets the redirecting out side to f you domain links won’t work.
But f you still wanna see that on yow BrowserRouter then on the Route Component use render, instead of component

```js
<Route path=“the-path” render={()=>window.location-and-stuff} />
```

Comment: In my actual application I'm using this to redirect from a json POST. That is, someone submits a form on the website, and this redirects to the next page, so I can't just use anchor tags. I hadn't tried using `render` before, but when I did try it, it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I don't need to use React at all: to do the redirect I can use plain javascript and just do `window.location.href = "example.com"`