# Redirection using <Redirect /> from react-router

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I need to redirect to a completely new application when I click on a button in my app. This means that from URL: localhost:8080, I need to be redirected to stackoverflow.com
If I use `<Redirect to="stackoverflow.com"/>` I get this: http://localhost:8080/https://stackoverflow.com So it attaches the new address to the old one, and what I need is to redirect me to stackoverflow.com.
Is there a way to do this using Redirect component from react-router? Thanks.

Comment: Just use anchor tag?

Comment: I was wondering if I can use this Redirect component or some other component from react similar like Redirect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

Comment: it does not, because non of the suggested solutions is what I was looking for, but thank you anyway