# How can I place a <dv> after a <Typography> in this code

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I learn React and now I tried in various way to get this to work from reading [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link) and also the [html div doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)

As the image show the text and link should be in a straight line not vertically stacked

[image]

Can someone help me with this or suggest some reading I can do to learn this maybe

```
<Box alignItems="center" display="flex" ml={-1}>
    <Checkbox checked={values.policy} name="policy" onChange={handleChange} />
    <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="body1">
        I have read the
        <div role="article">
            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://greta.portplays.com/Privacy%20Policy.html">
                Privacy Policy
            </a>
        </div>
    </Typography>
</Box>
<Box alignItems="center" display="flex" ml={-1}>
    <Checkbox checked={values.policy} name="Terms" onChange={handleChange} />
    <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="body1">
        I have read the
        <div role="article">
            <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://greta.portplays.com/Terms%20of%20Service.html">
                Terms and Conditions
            </a>
        </div>
    </Typography>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
...
 I have read the
            <span role="article">
                <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="http://greta.portplays.com/Privacy%20Policy.html">
                    Privacy Policy
                </a>
            </span>
```

But since `a` is an `inline` element this would work without the `span` too. You can read a bit more on inline and block elements in css.

Comment: I did try that but I hade <li> to many I think thanks a bunch