# Href URL is nested on same page

Tags: reactjs

I am using React. I have a component called profileTop. I am currently at url localhost:3000/profile/3935935721

```
const ProfileTop = ({profile: {status,company,location,website,social,user:{avatar, name}}}) => {
    return (
 <div class="icons my-1">
              {website && (<a href= "www.google.com" target="_self" rel="noopener noreferrer">
              <i class="fas fa-globe fa-2x"></i>
            </a>)}
)
```

When I click at that a tag the url becomes localhost:3000/profile/www.google.com instead of [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).
What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add http:// or https://

```
<a href="https://google.com">
```

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link).